# Strange error Looping through nested Laravel collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a collection I get by doing the following:

```
public function index(){
    $responseTemplates = ResponseTemplate::with('questions.answers')->get();
    return $responseTemplates;
}
```

ResponseTemplate.php

```
class ResponseTemplate extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['questions'];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
    }
}
```

Question.php

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'order'
    ];

    public function responseTemplates(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ResponseTemplate');
    }
}
```

Which returns this collection:

```
[  
   {  
      id:1,
      questions:[  
         {  
            id:4,
            order:999999,
            title:"*How old are you",
            pivot:{  
               response_template_id:1,
               question_id:4
            },
            answers:[  
               {  
                  id:1,
                  title:"10+",
                  question_id:4,
                  created_at:null,
                  updated_at:"2017-05-24 09:12:34"
               },
               {  
                  id:2,
                  title:"20+",
                  question_id:4,
                  created_at:"2017-05-24 08:40:10",
                  updated_at:"2017-05-24 09:12:34"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            id:3,
            order:999999,
            title:"*Where are you from",
            pivot:{  
               response_template_id:1,
               question_id:3
            },
            answers:[  
               {  
                  id:17,
                  title:"North",
                  question_id:3,
                  created_at:"2017-05-24 09:11:03",
                  updated_at:"2017-05-24 09:11:11"
               },
               {  
                  id:18,
                  title:"South",
                  question_id:3,
                  created_at:"2017-05-24 09:11:19",
                  updated_at:"2017-05-24 09:11:28"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      created_at:"2017-05-24 15:03:59",
      updated_at:"2017-05-24 15:03:59"
   },
   {  
      id:10,
      questions:[  
         {  
            id:8,
            order:999999,
            title:"*How old are you",
            pivot:{  
               response_template_id:10,
               question_id:8
            },
            answers:[  
               {  
                  id:36,
                  title:"30+",
                  question_id:8,
                  created_at:"2017-05-24 09:53:17",
                  updated_at:"2017-05-24 09:55:17"
               },
               {  
                  id:37,
                  title:"40+",
                  question_id:8,
                  created_at:"2017-05-24 09:55:17",
                  updated_at:"2017-05-24 09:55:27"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      created_at:"2017-05-25 11:13:47",
      updated_at:"2017-05-25 11:13:47"
   }
]
```

This is exactly as I'd expect.

If I replace my `index()` function with the below:

```
$responseTemplates = ResponseTemplate::with('questions.answers')->get();
return $responseTemplates[0];
```

I get this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    questions: [
        {
            id: 4,
            order: 999999, // etc
```

Which is also correct.

But if I return

```
$responseTemplates = ResponseTemplate::with('questions.answers')->get();
return $responseTemplates[0]->questions;
```

I just get an empty string. The same goes for if I go like this:

```
@foreach($responseTemplates as $template)
    <div>
        Template!
        @foreach($template->questions as $question)
```

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

I know I must be doing something super dumb, but can't put my finger on it. I'm sure I've done this a thousand times in the past with no issues at all.

Can anyone help me make my second foreach statement work?

Comment: Tried `@foreach($template['questions'] as $question)` ?

Comment: which foreach is giving the error

Comment: @Exprator The second foreach, the first one is looping through the array fine, but the second says there is nothing to loop through.

Comment: ok do one thing print the $template and show the output, hope can understand that

Comment: @linktoahref just tried it – exactly the same error.

Comment: @Exprator ah my goodness, I found it. I did a `var_dump` of `$template` during the loop and got `string 0` for questions. Then I noticed this in my ResponseTemplate.php `protected $fillable = ['questions'];`... facepalm. The attribute and relation have the same name. Stupid error! Thanks for helping me fix it.

Comment: You are welcome @Djave bro